# How to Build AppCompatDialog From AlertDialog.Builder or Equivalent?

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat, appcompatdialog

Before this I used a `DialogBuilder` to create `AlertDialog` like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
...
...
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

How can I build the new `AppCompatDialog` from a dialog builder, or is there another new equivalent way to do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just found the solution. I should import

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

and then `AppCompatDialog dialog = builder.create()` will work.

Answer (score 17):

If you would like to use an `AlertDialog`, just import the new `supprt v 22.1` and use a code like this (pay attention to the import):

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

AlertDialog.Builder builder =
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
            builder.setTitle("Dialog");
            builder.setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            builder.show();
```

If

Comment: when using `builder.setView(v) ` for `appcompatdialog` the size of dialog is max instead of just wrapping the component. here `v` is a `recyclerview`, which has variable no. of items

Comment: what should I do so that the size of dialog changes according no. of `recyclerview` items ?

Answer (score 6):

`android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog` is direct parent class of `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`, wherever you can use `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`, you can use `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog`.

Answer (score 4):

I've just moved all my `android.app.AlertDialog` to `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`.

After some testing with 4.X emulators I've found that for a simple dialog it's enough to simply change the import. But for multiple choice dialogs, additionally, you need to do `AppCompatDialog alert = builder.create();` to get the Material Design style dialogs (on 4.X).

To be clear, if you have a simple dialog like this one:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
builder.setIcon(resId)
.setTitle(title)
.setMessage(msg)
.setCancelable(isCalncelable)
.setPositiveButton(btn1, listener1);
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Changing the import will suffice :)

But for a **multi choice dialog**, you need to use `AppCompatDialog` like this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog;

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Choose something")
.setPositiveButton(...)
.setMultiChoiceItems(mStringArray, mSelectedArray, SomeFragment.this);
AppCompatDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Then you get the nice Material Design look on 4.X devices.

*Now the fun part!*

For a multi choice dialog, *on a 5.X device*, the native version (`android.app.AlertDialog`) shows the check-boxes at the *left*, correctly following the [Material Design spec](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-confirmation-dialogs). But if you use the support dialogs, then the check-boxes will appear at the *right*. WTF!

On the long term, as Android 5+ gains market share, you will want to switch back to native dialogs.